# Directional derivative given a function and a partial derivative

Tags: calculus

Given the function

$f(x,y)=g(7x+2y), g'(11)=1$

Find the directional derivative $D_ uf(1,2)$ of f in the point $(1,2)$ in the direction of $u=(1,0)$

I know that directional derivatives are calculated by $\nabla f(x,y)*u$ but given the additional information of $g'(11)=1$ I am uncertain how to find the directional derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_x=7g'(7x+2y), f_y=2g'(7x+2y)$ $f_x(1,2)=7g'(11)=7, f_y(1,2)=2g'(11)=2$ so $\nabla f(1,2)=(7,2), \nabla f \cdot u= 7$

Comment: It should equal 7(unless the book is incorrect). How do you go from $\nabla f(1,2)=(77,22), \nabla f \cdot u= 77$. I do not understand this calculation. 

Edit: I just noticed your error with double digits. Let me just  check if I understand it correctly now.

Comment: Yeah I'm dumb I thought g'(11) was 11

Comment: I'm still uncertain how you go from $\nabla f(1,2)=(7,2), \nabla f \cdot u= 7$. Could you show me more step's in your calculation?

Comment: Ok I'll edit my answer

Comment: I'm not sure how you calculate $7g'(11)=7$ and $2g'(11)=2$.

What if given other values: $g'(11)=2$ and $u=(2,1)$

Comment: In the question it says g'(11)=1

Comment: I edited my comment. I accidently hit "add comment" too early.

Comment: So you need to find the unit vector so u in the your case would be (2/(sqrt(2^2+1^2), 1/sqrt(5)) and if g'(11) was different then you would just plug in that different value in your calculation.

Answer (score 1):

The directional derivative in the direction of $(1,0)$ is just the partial derivative with respect to $x$. By the chain rule, $${\partial f\over\partial x}=g'(7x+2y){\partial(7x+2y)\over\partial x}=7g'(7x+2y).$$ Evaluated at $(x,y)=(1,2)$, this is $7g'(11)=7\cdot1=7$.

More generally, use the chain rule to find $$\nabla f=g'(7x+2y)\nabla(7x+2y)=g'(7x+2y)(7,2),$$ so $\nabla f\cdot u=g'(7x+2y)(7u_x,2u_y)$. At $(x,y)=(1,2)$, this equals $g'(11)(7u_x,2u_y)=(7u_x,2u_y)$.